# Modifying variable in Subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a query regarding subclass & modifying instance variable in Objective-C.

Suppose I have class say **A** with .h & .m

```
@interface A : NSObject
  @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *myVariable;
@end

@implementation A
  -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.myVariable=@"123";
    }
   @end
```

A has two subclasses Say **B** & **C**

```
 @interface B : A
  {
  }
 @end

@implementation B

  -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.myVariable = @"Modified Here";
   }
@end
```

Now when I try to access 'myVariable' in subclass C

```
@interface C : A
 {
 }
    @end

@implementation C

 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
       NSLog(@"Value is : %@",self.myVariable);
    }
@end
```

In log i found *Value is : 123*

Can anyone help me to understand why I am not getting updated value of var 'myVariable' which is being modified in class B.

Comment: Because `C` knows nothing about `B`. It doesn't matter that they have a common ancestor. No offence, but it seems that you should read up on Object Oriented Programming and its principles.

Comment: You are logging the value inside C which inherits from A. You will get the string value initialized in A.

Comment: If you made C inherit from B it would be a different matter

Comment: Because C and A  are two different and has different memory space.

Comment: You created two different class B & C which is a subclass of A. And these classes have all their separate properties like `myVariable` with different values. You set initially `123` to `myVariable` on class A so C directly get this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              A ("123")
              |
              |
        --------------
       |              |
       B              C
("Modified Here")  ("123") this is inherited from A

  So it prints "123"
```